# jQuery filter with multiple classes how to "delete" one filter without deleting results with both classes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying unsuccessfully to create a filtering solution only with HTML, CSS and jQuery. No luck in getting something "exclusive" in its functioning (example below).

I am creating a filtering solution, as such :

- when no checkbox is checked, nothing is shown
- for each checkbox checked, corresponding button is shown (with classes)
- if two are checked, only buttons with both classes are shown
- if one of those checkboxes is unchecked, then the added selective element is cancelled.

Example :

- A is BLUE and WHITE
- B is WHITE and GREY
- C is BLUE and WHITE and ORANGE
- D is BLUE and GOLD

If I select BLUE i will have : A and C and D as results

If I select both BLUE and WHITE I will have : A and C as results

As I uncheck WHITE, I should have again A and C and D as results

Currently, when checking, I can't get to have only the two classes checked, and when unchecking, it only hides the elements with the corresponding classes.

In my example, that means that :

- If I have selected both BLUE and WHITE I have A, B, C and D as results.
- And when I uncheck WHITE, I will only have D as a result.

Can somebody please help me? Thank you in advance !

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.form-checkbox form input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("."+$(this).attr('id')).css('display', 'inline-flex');
        } else {
            $("."+$(this).attr('id')).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var $all = $('.form-checkbox form input[type="checkbox"]');
    function refresh() {
        $(".card").hide(); // First hide all
        if (!$all.is(":checked")) return; // If nothing checked: that's it
        var ids = $all.filter(":checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('id'); // Collect all the IDs of the selected items
        }).get().join("."); // ... and join them into one CSS class selector
        $("." + ids).css('display', 'inline-flex'); // Show those only
    }
    $all.click(refresh);
    refresh(); // Run immediately
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-checkbox"> 
    <form>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="apples">Apples</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="pears">Pears</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="cucumbers">Cucumbers</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="dates">Dates</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="eggs">Eggs</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="figs">Figs</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="grapes">Grapes</label>
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="card dates apples"><button>dates-apples</button></li>
    <li class="card dates apples cucumbers"><button>dates-apples-cucumbers</button></li>
    <li class="card dates eggs"><button>dates-eggs</button></li>
    <li class="card figs apples"><button>figs-apples</button></li>
    <li class="card dates grapes apples"><button>dates-grapes-apples</button></li>
    <li class="card dates cucumbers"><button>dates-cucumbers</button></li>
    <li class="card dates pears apples"><button>dates-pears-apples</button></li>
    <li class="card dates apples"><button>dates-apples</button></li>
    <li class="card pears dates apples eggs"><button>pears-dates-apples-eggs</button></li>
    <li class="card dates eggs"><button>dates-eggs-2</button></li>
    <li class="card "><button>nothing</button></li>
    <li class="card figs"><button>figs</button></li>
    <li class="card dates apples grapes"><button>dates-apples-grapes</button></li>
    <li class="card figs pears"><button>figs-pears</button></li>
    <li class="card cucumbers figs"><button>cucumbers-figs</button></li>
</ul>
```